# Are there communities that follow the Rambam?

Tags: halacha, history, rambam, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, tzibur-community

At one point, many Sefardic communities followed the Mishneh Torah. As time went on, it seems that the sefardim accepted the Beit Yosef.
Besides for Yemenites, were there any communities that, until recently, mainly followed the halachot of the Mishneh Torah?
Someone told me that there was a city in Morocco that completely followed the Rambam. Does anybody know if that is correct?

Comment: communities of banei anusim follow rambam, communities in actual spain and portugal and maghrab followed rambam. not sure exactly who what when where but that is what i have heard.